# EF Code first query returns 0

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, code-first

I try to get all rows from a table in the database, but the list returns empty.
Screenshot if rows in database:
https://gyazo.com/37957807543227e4c6b2df9d30b1b970

```
///Database connectie
var dbconn = new FilmsContext();


///Alles uit de database halen
List<Films> list = dbconn.Films.ToList();
```

Database setup

```
public class FilmsContext : DbContext
    {

        public FilmsContext() : base("FilmsContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Films> Films { get; set; }
    }
```

Table setup

```
public class Films
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string beschrijving { get; set; }
        public string afbeelding { get; set; }
        public string auteur { get; set; }
        public int sterren { get; set; }
        public string websitelink { get; set; }
        public DateTime datum { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where is the Views..??
And your connection string because the code you provide is fine.

Comment: Show your web config DB connection.

Comment: Check the connectionstring(s) and find out how many copies of the database you have.

Comment: This is my app.config

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL CE chances are that the database file is being created in the bin\debug folder, but you're pointing somewhere else.

This is especially true if you're using `DropCreateDatabaseAlways`.